# Making a cubical array of spheres with a wave through the cube

Tags: modifiers

I am a noob to blender but have some 3D experience. I am trying to make a cube of spheres and then make an animation of a wave go through the cube.
Is there a way to stack particle planes so they all do the same thing? Or maybe its easier to do a cube array...

Is it possible to animate a bezier curve with an array following it?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a grid or subdivided plane, delete the faces and edges and add an [array modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html) to get a 3d grid of vertices.

[image]

Add a sphere object then shift-select the cube of vertices and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to make the vertices [the parent](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/parents.html) of the sphere. In the vertices properties enable dupliverts and you will then see a sphere duplicated at the location of each vertex.

[image]

[image]

Now add a [wave modifer](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/wave.html) -

[image]

Here is a sample file[image]

To animate curves you can add [a hook](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html) to each point and then animate the location of the hook object. The [curve modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) can be used after an array modifier to deform a duplicated object along the curve.

[image]